# TypeError: 'cards' is Undefined when Transitioning from Page to App Directory in Next.js to load data staticly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, app-router

I was initially working with the page directory of Next.js to load my data statically. Now, I'm working with the app directory.

In the page directory, I used to load data statically like this:

```js
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const cards = await getCards();
  return { props: { cards } };
};
```

Here's what I'm currently trying in the app directory:

```js
export async function generateStaticParams() {
 const cards = await getCards();

 return { props: { cards } };
}
```

> However, I encounter the following error: TypeError: works is undefined (When I try to map my data).

getCards is functioning correctly; the issue seems to be in how I retrieve the data from it.